# Why my directive doesn't show a String I'm passing to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build my second directive in Angular. I'm facing a problem that is driving me crazy. I'm new to angular, trying to studying it, following [this very useful explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives) and also [this great tutorial](http://suhairhassan.com/2013/10/21/refactoring-to-angularjs-directive.html#.U3FHdF76lRz), but I don't understand why, I can't pass a simple string to the directive.

This is my super simple directive's code:

```
uxctModule.directive('postIt', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      scope:{
         message: "@"
      },

      template:"<div>Received: {{message}}</div>"
  };
});
```

I'm trying to pass a very simple string to it.

This is my markup:

```
 <div post-it message='{{postItContent}}'></div>
```

where `postItComment` is scope variable coming from its controller:

```
 $scope.postItContent = "THIS IS A STRING DECLARED IN MY CONTROLLER";
```

What's happening? Could someone please give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this JS Fiddle, your solution works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ahchurch/S6dBE/1/

Not for nothing but in your question (not sure if it's a typo or you just haven't noticed) - $scope.postItContent is not what you're binding your message to. Your binding is {{postItComment}}.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('postIt', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      scope:{
         message: "@"
      },

      template:"<div>Received: {{message}}</div>"
  };
});
//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Superhero';
}
```

Comment: Also found it to work in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sWnRg7XXEpJwRf1OaZ0T?p=preview). The culprit must either the mismatch you presented or some other.

Comment: I want to kill myself, really. This is what happens when you work during the night too hard instead of having rest. I was so sure the error was in the directive that I didn't realize the error was that I declared the variable in the WRONG CONTROLLER. Shame on me.

Comment: just to understand and to learn, what to do you mean by '$scope.postItContent is not what you're binding your message to. Your binding is {{postItComment}}.'

Comment: He means you had one variable name set in your controller and another name to be interpolated in your directive attribute: `'postItContent' !== 'postItComment'` but as he seemed to indicate it could have just been a typo in your question (not in your real code)

Comment: aaaah sorry yes it's a typo, fixing it